# write a number of strings using awk

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

I have data in text in a 4 columns but the last column is a text (contains variable strings) like as shown below

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
5678    567     56      hello
1234    123     12      hello there
```

I want to write or display only the 4th column using `awk` like:
`awk '{print $4}'` but column4 only shows the first string.
How can I be able to show text using `awk` or any other formatting command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is probably a mix of `tr` (to ensure there's only one space between each column) and `cut` to grab the 4th and subsequent columns:

```
$ cat test.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 4- -d ' '
Column4
hello
hello there
```

If you're certain that all the columns are alligned, with spaces (not tabs), then this is shorter:

```
$ cut -c 25- < test.txt
Column4
hello
hello there
```

And the obligatory `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '{ $1=$2=$3=""; print $0 }' < test.txt
   Column4
   hello
   hello there
```

Note the whitespace at the start of each line of output, compared to the previous two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Column 4 is getting split when you use {print $4} because awk interprets and space (for example between "hello" and "there") as a delimiter, and in this example the "there" would be in field 5.

Depending on exactly how your file is formatted, there are a number of possible answers (some easier than others).

If all of the columns are separated by a single tab character, use

`awk -F \t '{print $4}'`
(-F here sets the filed separator to a single tab)

If all of the columns are separator by one or more tab characters, use

`awk -F '[\t]+' '{print $4}'`
(-F here sets the field separator to one or more tabs)

If the first there columns are always a fixed number of characters (say 20) then use

`awk '{print substr($0, 21)}'`

(the substr command simply prints the input lime from the 21st character to the end)

or, if none of the above

`awk '{for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s ", $i
     print ""}'`

(this loop prints all fields from the fourth to the end of the line)

Answer (score 0):

If the format of your input file is that each column is separated by two or more spaces, and a valid entry in column 4 will never have more than one space in a row, you could use the following solution, where the field separator is set to two or more spaces.

`awk -F " [ ]+" '{print $4}'`

Sample output:

`hello
hello there`

(Note that the header "Column4" was rejected because there is only one space between each of the headings)